# populate data on button click from the corresponding datatables row in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html) is a similar solution, only difference is I want to populate the row's data in the bootstrap modal on a button click. In every row there is a button. But without using those `.responsive` scripts as used in the above link's example.

Here is the very basic example of my table.

```
 <table id="table1">
    <thead> <th>Table Data</th><th>Button</th>
    <td> $data </td> 
    <tr><td><button id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?> data-toggle="modal" class="pay" data-target="#myModal">Pay Fees</button></td></tr>
<div  class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-content">
 </div>
</div>
```

with Jquery the following works:

```
$(".pay").on( 'click', 'tr', function (){
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
      //pay_fees($id);
});
```

A Jquery solution would be preferred.

Comment: So you want to be able to click the plus button to view the row details in a modal ([like in your link](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html)), but then those fields should be editable? Is there a backing database that should be updated also?

Comment: no I want to happen this on click of my own button as in my table. this Plus  button requires me to include those .responsive scripts which I don't want to

Comment: Why don't you want to use it? We can't just write an entire customized plugin for you. You need to narrow the question down to a specific sub-task that you don't know how to do.

Comment: It's not about writing an entire plugin. It's just how to transfer data to the bootstrap modal of that specific row,  I mentioned the jquery function that works because... I suppose something like `table.row( this ).data()` could do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For now I have used the following code to achieve this:

```
$('#table1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr button', function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $(".modal-title").html(table.row($(this).parents(':eq(1)')).data()[0]);
} );
```